# c# => método que reciba dos colecciones que implementen IEnumerable<T> y devuelva un IEnumerable<T> con los valores repetidos

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando crear un método que reciba dos colecciones que implementen IEnumerable y devuelva como resultado un IEnumerable con los valores que coincidan en la misma posición utilizando Iteradores (IEnumerator).

El problema es que no consigo que los muestre, si en el main pongo el primer elemento en comun lo reconoce, pero no los siguientes. Y como no ponga el primer elemento en comun y sí el resto, no es capaz de detectarlos.

No sé si es problema del metodo o de los valores iniciales en el main¿?

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> Metodo<T>(IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
        {
            IList<T> res = new List<T>();
            IEnumerator<T> it_1 = a.GetEnumerator();
            IEnumerator<T> it_2 = b.GetEnumerator();
            int cont = 0;
            while (it_1.MoveNext() && it_2.MoveNext())
            {
                if (it_1.Current.Equals(it_2.Current))
                {
                    res.Add(it_1.Current);
                    cont++;
                    //continue;
                    //Console.Write(it_1.Current + " "); Imprime la posicion
                }
            }

            return res;
        }
```

Y en el main tengo:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nDos listas");
            List<char> aa = new List<char>();
            lista.Add('a');
            lista.Add('b');
            lista.Add('c');
            List<char> bb = new List<char>();
            lista.Add('x');
            lista.Add('b');
            lista.Add('c');

            var result = Metodo(aa, bb);
            foreach (var item in result)
                Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu `main` tienes mal asignada las variables.

Tu método que recibe las colecciones esta bien, el problema es que le envías las colecciones `aa` y `bb` nulas, ya que no se le asignan valores en ningún momento.

Realizas lo siguiente pero  `lista`  de donde sale?

```
List<char> aa = new List<char>();
lista.Add('a');
lista.Add('b');
lista.Add('c');
List<char> bb = new List<char>();
lista.Add('x');
lista.Add('b');
lista.Add('c');
```

Deberías cambiar eso por:

```
List<char> aa = new List<char>();
aa.Add('a');
aa.Add('b');
aa.Add('c');
List<char> bb = new List<char>();
bb.Add('x');
bb.Add('b');
bb.Add('c');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cierto!! tenia un monton de listas inicializadas y no me daba cuenta del error!, Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podria servir esto:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string> { "a.dll", "b1.dll" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string> { "A.dll", "b2.dll" };

var firstNotSecond = list1.Except(list2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
var secondNotFirst = list2.Except(list1, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

Luego unes firstNotSecond  + secondNotFirst y tendras elementos unicos ;)

O:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace YourProject.Extensions
{
    public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static bool SetwiseEquivalentTo<T>(this List<T> list, List<T> other)
            where T: IEquatable<T>
        {
            if (list.Except(other).Any())
                return false;
            if (other.Except(list).Any())
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Puede servirte este articulo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-generic-lists-for-differences

Saludos!